# Php, mysql coding error

Tags: php, mysql

Please tell me that where is error. I am in tention due to this,

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalooo1\includes\db.php:2 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\kalooo1\index.php(21): include() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalooo1\includes\db.php on line 2

**db.php**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");``
    mysql_select_db("kalooo");
?>
```

**index.php(21)**

```
include("includes/db.php");
```

Comment: Which version of php you are working with? `mysql_*` API is removed oin the actual php version

Comment: mysql_* functions have been removed in PHP7!

Comment: That's a _good_ error message. It means that you're using a newer version of PHP and can't use the _removed_ `mysql_*`-functions (which has been _deprecated_ since PHP 5.5) anymore.

Comment: i am new,.,.,.,. working on notpad++ .,.,.,.    feel dificulty .......

Comment: i want to work on php mysql and database,,,,,,

Comment: In manual for this function, it have said that it's _deprecated_ for several years. What editor you're using is irrelevant. Read about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error simple because you are using a newer version of php that does not support `mysql_*` functions, those functions have been depreciated and completely removed from the latest version of php.

You should use `mysqli` prepared  functions or `pdo` prepared statements.

using mysqli to connect to database you will use it like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "yourusername";
$password = "yourpassword";
$dbname = "yourdatabse";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

using PDO, you would connect like this:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'yourdb';
$user = 'yourusername';
$pass = 'yourpassword';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

?>
```

The are good tutorials on the net that you can use to better your understanding, I personally enjoy this site https://phpdelusions.net/pdo   You should visit it you will be a pro in no time.

Comment: <?php

try{
 $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname:phpblog",'root','');
$sth=$con->query("SELECT * FROM select_query");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row= $sth->fetch()){
 echo $row['Name']. "<br>";
 echo $row['Class']. "<br>";
 
 
 
 
 }
 catch(PDOExcepion $e){
  echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
 }
 
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");`

or use
store this in separate php file.
include that file like this. `include 'db.php';`
try this....

Comment: How does this actually answer the question?

Comment: #magnus how it will come wrong answer? I'm done that ryt

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. It still doesn't tell the OP _why_ he's having this issue, or why "mysqli_connect()" would help. Not saying that it's wrong, just that a good answer includes an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalooo1\index.php on line 23

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalooo1\index.php on line 24
$run_cats=mysqli_query($get_cats);
while ($cats_row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){

Comment: @mabubkr firstly check your DB is connected or not ?

Comment: please friendz tell me error.
<?php

try{
 $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname:phpblog",'root','');
$sth=$con->query("SELECT * FROM select_query");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row= $sth->fetch()){
 echo $row['Name']. "<br>";
 echo $row['Class']. "<br>";
 
 
 
 
 }
 catch(PDOExcepion $e){
  echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
 }
 
}
?>